# How to fix the error warning failed to connect to lvmetad no such file or directory falling back to internal scanning in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, boot-loader

My Ubuntu laptop which was working fine until recently. My desktop disappeared and all the desktop icons are gone. All I have access to is the terminal. In an attempt to fix the problem, I installed GNOME but it made the computer give the error:

> Warning! Failed to connect to lvmetad. No such file or directory Falling back to internal scanning.

I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to start *tty1* but I can't get to a graphical user interface. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?.

The operating system is ubuntu Linux

Comment: log in, then type "startx". (doesn't fix the lvmetad thing, but get's you "back in")